# submit() executes repeatedly&php receives only default value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, submit

I have a submit form using `POST` method, without a submit button.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="submit_cookie_form">
   <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="" id="cookie_form">
</form>
```

My goal:

1. Pass value to input hidden value attribute[*1]
2. Set the code to be executed/triggered when a value is passed to value attribute[*2]
3. Submit the form when a value is passed to value attribute[*3]=>ISSUE
4. Pass Javascript value('en' or 'jp') to php variable. [*4]=>ISSUE

[*3] =>
When I use `submit()` as follows to [*3], the page is being reloaded forever. It seems like the form is being submitted forever. Why does this happen, and how can I fix the code?

[*4] => Why does php only receive `'en'` value? Although, value attribute of `<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="" id="cookie_form">` perfectly recieves `'en'` and `'jp'` according to user's clicks on the webpage. How can I fix this?

```
 let latestCookie;

    $(document).on('ready', function(){

       if (localStorage.getItem("language") === null || localStorage.getItem("language") === flag.en){
         document.cookie = "language=en";

       } else if (localStorage.getItem("language") === flag.jp){
         document.cookie = "language=jp";
       }

        latestCookie = getCookieValue('language');
        document.getElementById('cookie_form').value = latestCookie; //[*1]
        setLang(latestCookie); //[*2]
     })


      $('#cookie_form').change(function(){
          $('#submit_cookie_form').submit(); }); //[*3]

      function setLang(chosenLang){
          $('#cookie_form').val(chosenLang).trigger('change');
        }
```

---

```
   <?php 
         if(isset($_POST['lang'])){     
           $lang=$_POST['lang'];   //[*4]
           echo $lang;
         }
         else{
           echo $lang;
         }
   ?>
```

Comment: any specific reason to save cookie value in hidden input?, because you can retrieve it by `$_COOKIE` in PHP.

Comment: [*4], because at the time your page your browser localstorage always be null so code setting it with `en` and then submit the form, that's why you got `en` always.

Comment: your `trigger('change')` causing the problem here in function `setLang`

Comment: Okay, from where you will get `flag.jp` this value? because I don't found the source of getting this value.

Comment: @ShaileshRathod then, how can I change the code? You're giving me ideas. but not really helping...

Comment: @ShaileshRathod I have deleted the code where you can add `flag.jp`. Here is the code `$('.dropdown-menu a img').on('click', function(){
            let flag = $(this).attr('src');
            $('#selected').attr('src', flag);
            let key = $('#selected').attr('src');
            localStorage.setItem("language", key);
            refreshPage();
            })`

Comment: @ShaileshRathod `const flag = {
             en: "img/flag_english.png",
             jp: "img/flag_japanese.png"
           };`

Comment: Okay, then in your `refreshPage()` function set value in cookie by `document.cookie = "language=en"` with what ever your value is and refresh the page, then in PHP by using $_COOKIE['language'] can will get the actually value you want.

Comment: you can check [here] (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) for more details about $_COOKIE

Comment: @ShaileshRathod why set cookie value inside `refreshPage()` and not inside the code I wrote in the question?? Also, php receives cookie value, but receives the old value. There is a time lag in php getting the latest cookie value from client-side.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dropdown-menu a img').on('click', function(){ 
    let flag = $(this).attr('src'); 
    $('#selected').attr('src', flag); 
    let key = $('#selected').attr('src'); 
    localStorage.setItem("language", key); 
    refreshPage(key); 
});
function refreshPage(key){
    window.location.href = '<php echo $_SERVER[\'PHP_SELF\']."?lang="; ?>'+key;
}
```

then in PHP you can get in GET method as a querystring.

```
<?php 
     if(isset($_REQUEST['lang'])){     
       $lang=$_REQUEST['lang'];   //[*4]
       echo $lang;
     }
     else{
       echo $lang;
     }
?>
```